# Which algorithm would be suitable for clustering a billion datapoints?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

I am running a K-means algorithm (using the `sklearn` implementation) on an aggregated dataset of ~350k datapoints on a 6 dimension hyper-plane (using 6 features).

I would like to do the same but in the "non-aggregated" version of my dataset, which is ~1b datapoints using the same 6 features

I know this is a very heavy task for K-means, the number of datapoints is just too big, even though the dimensions' size is pretty small.

Are there any suggestions of other algorithms that would help me on this task, apart from mini batch K-means ?

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html.  It gives at least a qualitative scaling for n_points, and m_clusters (dimensionality is not discussed much, either from utility of each algorithm or scalability perspective)